# Xamarin forms Entry decimal separator does not work properly on different CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an entry in xaml:

```
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                   FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Large"
                                   IsPassword="False" Keyboard="Numeric"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                   Text="{Binding MyNumber}"
                                   TextColor="{Binding PropertyTextColor, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"
                                   Completed="Entry_Completed"/>
```

When I have US culture-info everything works properly, but when culture info is changed I cannot enter a comma or dot separator for decimal input. For example, when I type 5 and enter ',' and type 5 then the value converts to 55. I tried to change the culture-info for the current thread, but it does not help.

```
    private decimal _myNumber;
    public decimal MyNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return myNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            if (_myNumber != value)
            {
                if (IsDivisible)
                    //_myNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(value, 2).ToString(), new CultureInfo("pl-PL"));
                    _ = decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("pl-PL"), out _count);
                else
                    _ = decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("pl-PL"), out _count);
                 // _myNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(value, 0).ToString(), new CultureInfo("pl-PL"));

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to work around this issue? Because as I understood this problem is related to the Samsung configuration or settings and it's a quite common problem in Xamarin.

Comment: if you just do `decimal.TryParse` without any of the other logic does it work?  .NET should handle this for you without needing all of this extra effort

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, because I already gain from 5,5 -> 55 on my setter when I set debugger, I can see that the value which comes is already 55 instead of 5,5. So parsing does not play a big role I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case i ended up needing to force the dot as the decimal separator for every culture. And in order to get the dot printed i also needed to create a custom renderer for the Entry in order to re-set the InputTypes flags.

If this sounds like a way you might want to follow, keep on reading.

What follows is a sample-minimal app to demonstrate how to force and use the dot as a decimal separator in Android for Xamarin.Forms

### Force the dot as the decimal separator

First we have to tell the App that no matter what culture is used, the dot has to be taken as the decimal separator:

```cs
public App()
{
    CultureInfo customCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;

    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

### Re-set InputType

Create a CustomEntry on your Xamarin.Forms shared project:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EntryDecimal
{
    public class MyCustomEntry : Entry
    {
    }
}
```

And then add the custom renderer on Android. To do this simply add a new class to the Android project called AndroidCustomEntryRenderer.cs with the following content:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

using Android.Widget;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using Android.Text.Method;
using Android.Content;
using EntryDecimal.Droid;
using EntryDecimal;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyCustomEntry), typeof(AndroidCustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace EntryDecimal.Droid
{
    public class AndroidCustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        private MyCustomEntry element;
        private EditText native;

        public AndroidCustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            //Java.Text.DecimalFormatSymbols.Instance.DecimalSeparator = '.';

            element = (MyCustomEntry)Element ?? null;
            native = Control as EditText;

            UpdateKeyboard();
        }


        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (Control == null) return;

            else if (e.PropertyName == InputView.KeyboardProperty.PropertyName)
                UpdateKeyboard();
        }

        private void UpdateKeyboard()
        {
            //Implementation of the numeric keyboard (we simply add the NumberFlagSigned)
            native = Control as EditText;

            var defaultNumericKeyboard = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
            var correnctNumericKeyboard = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;

            if (native.InputType == defaultNumericKeyboard)
            {
                native.InputType =
                Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber |
                Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned |
                Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
                native.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(string.Format("7890.-"));
            }
            else if (native.InputType == correnctNumericKeyboard)
            {
                // Even though in the next line the InputType is set to the same it is already set, this seems to 
                // fix the problem with the decimal separator: Namely, a local other than english is set, the point 
                // does not have any effect in the numeric keyboard. Re-setting the InputType seems to fix this.
                native.InputType =
                Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber |
                Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned |
                Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

And finally consume this:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EntryDecimal"
             x:Class="EntryDecimal.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <local:MyCustomEntry x:Name="MyEntry"  Keyboard="Numeric"
               WidthRequest="150"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                             Completed="MyCustomEntry_Completed"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This minimal blank app is working correctly on my side, accepting dot as decimal separator for any culture (like de [german] where decimal separator is ",").

Hope this works!