# How to solve the Galaxy numeric keyboard nightmare

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, numeric, samsung-galaxy

I've been struggling with the Samsung Galaxy numeric keyboard decimal separator nightmare.

I have an `Entry` on which I must only accept numeric values (including decimals), so in my xaml code I wrote `<Entry Keyboard="Numeric"/>` and it worked just fine on the VS19 android simulator. But when I run the app on my physical device (Samsung Galaxy S10+) the comma key is disabled and the `.-` key doesn't work (it types nothing).

I made some digging online and found a few solutions, but none worked for me.

**SOLUTION 1**
Forcing the app culture to pt-BR (because my phone system language is brazilian portuguese) by adding this code to `App()` (in `App.xaml.cs`):

```cs
private void SetCultureToPTBR()
{
    CultureInfo br = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = br;
}
```

But there were no changes.

**SOLUTION 2**
Setting input type on a custom renderer for entries:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace AppCoperNitro.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
                return;
            
            this.Control.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(true, true);
            this.Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
        }
    }
}
```

This method changed the `.-` key to a comma key, and it kinda works (it types a .), but the decimal place is ignored (if I type 2.3 the app receives it as 23).

**SOLUTION 3**
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839483/11417475), but the result was the same as solution 2.

I also tried combining these solutions and their variances, but nothing works the way it should. I don't even care if the entry shows a comma or a dot, I just need the decimal number to be received correctly.

Comment: Any useful suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26983521/199364) or [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1898)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the ways. According to your SOLUTION 2, the entry can input the `.`, so you can do something in the Entry's UnFocused event. Such as: // Use Gabic's code

```
 private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        Entry entry = sender as Entry;
        if (entry.Text.Length > 0 && Android.OS.Build.Manufacturer.Equals("Samsung", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
           { 
              string a = entry.Text.Replace('.', ',');
              entry.Text = a; 
           }
    }
```

And then add the event into the xaml:

```
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused"/>
```

Comment: I tried this code and I have no ideia why when debugging `a = "2.3"` as expected, but `f = 23`... so I changed `a` to `string a = entry.Text.Replace('.', ',');` and it worked on my samsung, but not on the emulator... guess some ifs and elses will do the job

Comment: In case anyone needs the complete if statement: `if (entry.Text.Length > 0 && Android.OS.Build.Manufacturer.Equals("Samsung", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) { string a = entry.Text.Replace('.', ','); entry.Text = a; }`